# $f(x)$ is irreducible but $f(x^n)$ is reducible

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Does there exist an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with degree greater than one such that for each $n>1$, $f(x^n)$ is reducible?

Comment: reducible where? it's always reducible in $\mathbb{C}$, It won't be in $\mathbb{R}$ necessarily.

Comment: Of coures in $\mathbb{Z}$[x]$.

Comment: You're right! The body problem is true. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

No. If $f(X)=g(X)h(X)$, then $f(X^n)=g(X^n)h(X^n)$.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question.

Comment: Question has been changed. You answered the original one.